# Why does the console stays open although the program is finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm currently working on a web crawler with the ability to abort at any time when the 'ESC'-button is pressed.
To check whether 'ESC' is pressed, I'm using a thread which sets a flag to signal the 'main'-function to terminate itself. Although this is working fine, the console window doesn't close after the program is finished. The only circumstance under which the console window is closing, is when 'ESC' is pressed immediatly after the thread starts (so before the while loop is starting; see comment in the code).

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

boolean exitCrawler{ false };
char URL[512];
CURL *curl;
int i{ 0 }, start{ 0 }, stop{ 0 }, urlCount{ 0 };
std::ofstream write;
std::deque <const char*> urls;
std::regex rgx("(?:http)[:](?://)[A-Za-z0-9]+.[A-Za-z0-9]+.[a-z]+/");
std::smatch sm;
std::string answer, content;
std::vector <std::string> detectedURLs;
unsigned short keyState;

auto analyzeContent() -> void;
auto crawlSite() -> int;
auto indexSite() -> void;
auto quitCrawler() -> void;
auto writeContent(char*, size_t, size_t)->size_t;

auto main() -> void {
    SetConsoleTitle(L"WebCrawler");
    write.open("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\urls.txt", std::ios::app);
    std::cout << "Welcome to the WebCrawler!" << std::endl << "URL (http://www.*.*/): ";
    std::cin >> URL;
    std::cout << "Starting to crawl the surface web. Press \"ESC\" at any time to cancel the crawler." << std::endl;
    urls.push_back(URL);
    std::thread qC(quitCrawler);
    qC.detach();
    //Press 'ESC' here to get the console window to close itself after the program finishes. If you press 'ESC' after the while loop starts, the console window will stay open.
    while (true) {
        std::string s(urls.front(), strlen(urls.front()));
        if (s.find("http://") == -1) {
            urls.pop_front();
            content = "";
            continue;
        }
        if (crawlSite() == 1) {
            urls.pop_front();
            content = "";
            continue;
        }
        analyzeContent();
        std::cout << "\rCrawled " << urlCount << " sites of the surface web.";
        urls.pop_front();
        if ((urls.size() == 0) || exitCrawler) {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Crawler terminating..." << std::endl;
    write.close();
}

auto analyzeContent() -> void {
    memset(&sm, 0, sizeof(sm));
    i = 0;
    std::string::const_iterator beginningIterator = content.cbegin();
    while (std::regex_search(beginningIterator, content.cend(), sm, rgx)) {
        beginningIterator = sm[0].second;
        if ((std::find(detectedURLs.begin(), detectedURLs.end(), sm[0])) == detectedURLs.end()) {
            urls.push_back(sm[0].str().c_str());
            i++;
        }
        detectedURLs.push_back(sm[0]);
    }
}

auto crawlSite() -> int {
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urls.front()) != CURLE_OK) {
        return 1;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeContent);
    if (curl_easy_perform(curl) != CURLE_OK) {
        return 1;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    indexSite();
    return 0;
}

auto indexSite() -> void {
    urlCount++;
    write << "&emsp;#" << urlCount << "&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;[" << urls.front() << "]/[...] --- {[...]} --- " << std::time(0) << "<br>" << std::endl;
}

auto quitCrawler() -> void {
    keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    while (true) {
        if (keyState != 0) {
            exitCrawler = true;
            break;
        }
        keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    }
}

auto writeContent(char* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb) -> size_t {
    content.append(buffer);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

To be honest, I do not have any clue why the program is staying open after the code is finished.
**Does anybody of you have any idea?**

Comment: Race condition on `exitCrawler` -> undefined behavior. Fix with `std::atomic<bool> exitCrawler;`. But that is probably not the cause.

Comment: Your program never finishes. Or, more technically correct, a process is only terminated, when all threads have terminated. Your `quitCrawler` thread never terminates.

Comment: @nwp Thank you for the hint, but as you already guessed, that's not the solution for the problem.

Comment: @llnspectable How can I do this then?

Comment: Change your thread procedure's loop to `while( !exitCrawler )`.

Comment: @IInspectable He has `if ((urls.size() == 0) || exitCrawler) break;` at the bottom which already does that. @Daniel Try to `qC.join()` at the end of main instead of `detach`ing, that way you can check if `qC` quits correctly.

Comment: @nwp: There's a `qC.detach()`, breaking the keyboard listener thread away from the primary thread. The primary thread terminates. The keyboard listener thread doesn't. Consequently, the process never terminates. And since the process owns handles to the console, the console never closes either. `qC.join()` prevents the primary thread from terminating. With that change, two threads never terminate. Hardly a step in the right direction. Introducing a termination condition into the keyboard listener thread is.

Comment: @IInspectable Somehow I don't see why the listener thread does not quit. Assuming it actually gets the escape key event it breaks out of its loop and quits. A breakpoint could determine if the `exitCrawler = true;`-line is ever reached.

Comment: @nwp: You are correct. I overlooked the `break` statement.

Comment: @nwp It definitely is reached. I already tested that with `std::cout`. And as I also stated in the inital post, there is a circumstance at which the program as you can see it above is working.

Comment: My crystal ball says that windows does not like the main thread finishing before other threads. Sometimes that happens and your program is stuck, sometimes it doesn't and everything is good. Try removing the `detach` and add the `join`.

Comment: Adding `qC.join()` at the end of main doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: @nwp The thread (for checking if 'ESC' is pressed) **never** ends before the main thread, I checked that with `std::cout`. Or does it persist after its code is finished?

Comment: So when you attach the debugger to the process after it has "exited" how many threads are running and what are they doing?